# Save the folder path for loading UWP

Tags: c#, image, uwp

Save the folder path for loading

I uploaded images from a folder selected by a FilePicker but, I would like (after the first time I chose the folder) that when I start the app, automatically loads the selected folder, without having to retrieve it from the picker file every time.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="btnPickFolder" 
            Content="Pick Folder" 
            Click="btnPickFolder_Click" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="10,10,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Grid x:Name="GridShowImages" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,52,20,20">
        <GridView x:Name="ListViewImage" ItemsSource="{x:Bind listImage}">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SingleImage">
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageToLoad}" 
                           Margin="5" 
                           Width="300" 
                           Height="168.75"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<SingleImage> listImage = new ObservableCollection<SingleImage>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnPickFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        StorageFolder SelectFolderToLoad = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", SelectFolderToLoad);

        foreach (var file in await SelectFolderToLoad.GetFilesAsync())
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            bmp.SetSource(stream);
            listImage.Add(new SingleImage() { ImageToLoad = bmp });
            StorageFolder StorageParent = await file.GetParentAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

SingleImage class:

```
public class SingleImage
{
    public BitmapImage ImageToLoad { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `FutureAccesList` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions#Windows_Storage_AccessCache_StorageApplicationPermissions_FutureAccessList) to keep access to the selected folder / file after your app restarts

Comment: Thanks Dave for the answer... I saw the link but, I can not adapt it to my example .. because I use an FolderPicker not a FileSavePicker... Can you give an example?

Comment: I managed to use the example, but how do I load the app to take advantage of the saved permission then access the folder?

Comment: The [StorageItemAccessList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist) takes both files and folders, so you just pass your folder to the same API.

You need to save the token to your local app storage somewhere though, then you use the token on app load to retrieve the file with `GetFolderAsync` on the Future Access List.